# Sentence structure of negative interrogative sentences

Tags: interrogatives

I was reading Jane Austen's "Pride and Prejudice", when I came across a line whose structure I cannot understand. The line is "Is not he a charming man?".

Shouldn't it be "Is he not a charming man?"?

I'm confused as to what is the difference between the two of them. I would really appreciate if someone could explain the difference between the two sentence structures.

Comment: Take a look at this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Is+he+not%2C+is+not+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIs%20he%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20he%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Don't forget that Pride and Prejudice was written a long time ago. Would you say the same about *isn't he a charming man*, and what's the difference?

Comment: @LucianSava Thanks Lucian. That clearly indicates that one of the sentences is not used anymore.

Comment: @Minty Thank you. I do have that in mind. I know that language evolves and changes over time. I was just not sure because when we say "isn't it?"  It means "is it not?". But  in the book the line was "is not he". This is what has been confusing me.

Comment: But *isn't it* is a contraction of *is not it*, isn't it? And it means *is it not*, doesn't it? Similarly *isn't he* is a contraction of *is not he* and means the same as *is he not*. The word order in your sentence is now very unusual in the full form - but the fact that it is common in the contracted form is a good indication that the full form was common at some point in the past.